# Populate Google Sheet with data from HTML service

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm creating a Google Sheet with a linked HTML file for users to create and plan business trip itineraries easily. What I need to do is get the info from the HTML doc and populate certain cells on the google sheet when a button is clicked.

Here's a simplified version of my HTML doc:

```
      <div id = "sortable" class="ui-state">

        <div class = "sortableItem day">Monday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result1">Meeting1</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result2">Meeting2</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result3">Meeting3</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result4">Meeting4</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result5">Meeting5</div>

 <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg center-block" id="click">Update itinerary</button>
</div>
```

I have code written so that the meeting order can changed with drag and drop. Once the itinerary is in the right order, user should click on the button and it should update the google sheet (Cells A2: A5) with the new meeting order.

I have an array variable that I update with the new meeting order as follows when the button is clicked:

```
  var newOrder = [];

  $("#click").click(function(){
  for(var i=0; i <= 5; i++) {
  newOrder.push(sortable.children[i].innerHTML)
  }
})
```

This part is working fine as when I alert newOrder, the array is appearing correctly. But how do I then access this array on the Google Sheet side to update the cells?

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML Button `onClick()` call this :  `onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(saved()).yourServerFunction(this.form)"`

HTML Sampple,

```
<form class="form-style-7" id="myForm">
<ul>
<li>
    <label for="inbox">Inbox Filter</label>
    <input type="text" id="inboxVal" name="inboxVal" maxlength="100">
    <span>Enter Inbox Search Criteria Here</span>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="button" value="Create Rule"  onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(saved()).processForm(this.form)">
</li>
</ul>
</form>
 <script>
 function saved()
 {
  //Some Activity
 }
 </script>
```

Here `saved()` will be called on your HTML page if you want to perform any operation after submitting function.

On server side (i.e. in Appscript) write a normal function like below,

```
function yourServerFunction(myForm) {
  Logger.log("INFO:       Processing values: "+myForm.inboxVal);
}
```

Comment: thanks. What I seem to be struggling with is getting the actual data to be read on the server side. My form does not consist of inputs but divs... I need to read the innerHTML of these divs and populate them on the google sheet but when I try to access this data, I always get undefined

Comment: Can you add one hidden field in your form? Then is `saved()` function assign it the array values by '#' separated. On the form you will receive this hidden field in the same way as normal input.

Comment: Just to add to this, when I change the 'div' to an 'input type="text"' then I can get this to work as I set the name of the input and read that. But div doesn't take name attribute so how can I access the contents...?

Comment: I think that is separate question as this one says you have values array with you but you are not able to access it on Spread sheet side.

Comment: yes that's right, sorry was trying to test on a lower level just to see if I can pull anything through. Not sure about the hidden field idea as the positioning of the elements needs to be dynamic because of the drag and drop element. Could I share the google sheet with you so you can see how it is supposed to look?